# How to calculate the $f(x)=\int _1^x\cos^2(e^t) \, dt$?

Tags: integration

Question, calculate $(f^{-1})'(0)$ with  $f(x)=\int _1^x\cos^2(e^t) \, dt$?

I think even before that what does $\int _1^x$ mean? Are we computing a definite integral here? I don't think so because of the $x$ variable? What kind of integral is this or is it just called the anti-derivative?

Do I use the fundamental theorem of calculus ($F(a) - F(b)$)

After finding $f(x)$ I think I am fine. I will swap $x$ and $y$ and find the derivative at $0$.

Comment: The point of this exercise is that you cannot write $f(x)$ in terms of elementary functions. Think of something else! Yes. It is the definite integral with $t$ ranging over the interval $[1,x]$.

Comment: Note $f(1)=0$, and recall that $(F^{-1})'(F(x)) = 1/F'(x)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I don't think that's the point. The point is that you don't need to compute this integral in order to find the derivative.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm aware :-) I did phrase it poorly.

Comment: @azif00 Hi azif thanks for commenting but how did you get that? Why is that true?

Comment: @GoNK It is the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Comment: @azif00 Yes, sorry I watched a video on Khan academy about it. Can you please check the answer provided by WW1 and my comment? Many thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=\int _1^x\cos^2(e^t)\,dt$

then $f(1) = 0$ and $$f'(x) = \cos^2( e^x)$$

so  $$(f^{-1} )' (0) = (f^{-1} )' (f(1))  = \frac 1{   \cos^2( e)  }  $$

Comment: Hi WW1, thanks for your answer. I watched a khan academy video and I get the rule now. So $(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$ so instead of $x$, substitute $f(1)$, but how did you get $\cos(e)$

Comment: actually the rule is $$(f^{-1})'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$$
as stated in the comment by Asif00
we get $\cos^2(e)$ just by plugging in $x=1$ and using $e^1=e$